# I don't know how to do a list like this

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I'm using Jquery Mobile
I'm tring to do a list for a web app, but when I resize the window, the list won't resize to fit in new screen.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kavan/0gt67g1m/1/)

```
<ul data-role="none">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <div class="ev">
        <div class="fot">
          <img src="img/football.png" width="80px" height="80px">
        </div>
        <div class="contef">
          <h2>Torneo en Barcelona</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="contef_cn">
          <p>Torneo de futbol sala en barcelona centro</strong>
            <br>Incripcion L-V 9:00 apartir del dia 21/2/2069</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!--fin-->
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Your fiddle actually does resize to the window, only the content is 105px wider than the window because of the relatively positioned divs. You can see what happens better in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/0gt67g1m/2/) where I moved everything a bit to the left. So the solution is to plan your layout better. For example, float the image instead of trying to move the other elements.

Comment: change none to <ul data-role="page"> -- https://jsfiddle.net/63mzgqm7/

Comment: @Tasos Your solution doesn't really solve the OP's problem, it just hides the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Mr Lister what do you mean. my demo takes out the user agent styles for the ul  http://s21.postimg.org/6efm6hs2f/Capture.png . actually this <ul data-role="page"> is supposed to <ul data-role="listview"> i though it was a div

Comment: @Tasos Then which problem were you solving? The OP said, "when I resize the window, the list won't resize to fit in new screen."

Comment: @Mr Lister The Op Needs to go here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/ and vew the demos on how to use JQM properly.